# Is ArcGIS Online suitable for storing rasters which need further processing?

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, raster-calculator

I have a geo-referenced RGB aerial image, which I've added to a new MXD. Now I wish to share it with other people, so I publish the MXD to ArcGIS Online.

Unless I'm mistaken, the only option for publishing the raster is to store it as a Tiled layer.

Is it possible to perform further analysis on this tiled layer on ArcGIS Online (for example, to calculate the NDVI) or is the tiled layer on ArcGIS Online only suitable for visualisation?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a desktop software like ArcGIS Desktop or Pro or some other remote sensing software to process raster data. A served tiled layer is simply a bunch of small cached images. However, you may consume and use a hosted vector geoprocessing services on AGOL.

Comment: but can someone process the raster data in ArcMap or Pro *once it has been uploaded to ArcGIS Online as a tiled layer*, assuming that they don't have access to the raw input data? (I suspect that the answer is no, because the data has been degraded into the tiled format for presentation, but I'm hoping to get confirmation of this). thanks

Comment: The desktop tool would have to rasterize it into a local raster layer then process against it.  I do not think the tile layer would have the native additional bands still (like band 4) to create an NDVI result.

Comment: You would have to upload a zipped gdb with the raster dataset and then your users could DL and unzip the data for further processing. When you have the finalized data you could publish as a tile layer, if its elevation it can be published as a hosted elevation layer. If you wanted to use an imagery service this would have to be served through ArcGIS Enterprise and brought into AGOL where users could render the layer as they choose.